# Object Pooling in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, .net, unity3d

I've made 2 object pooling classes -

**`MonoObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour`** - can hold a single bucket of pooled objects of 1 type.

**`PolyObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour`** - can hold multiple buckets of pooled objects of different types.

The object to pool information is store in a **`class PooledObject`**

```
/// <summary>
/// Information holder for a pooled object
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class PooledObject
{
    [Tooltip(@"Name is used to differ the objects from one another")]
    public string Name;

    [Tooltip(@"What object should be created ?")]
    public GameObject Object;

    [Range(1, 10000)] [Tooltip(@"How much objects should be created ?")]
    public int Amount;

    [Tooltip(@"Can new objects be created in case there are none left ?")]
    public bool CanGrow;

    [Tooltip(@"False - objects must be created manually using Populate method
True - objects will be created automatically on awake")]
    public bool CreateOnAwake;
}
```

Which is later used in the 2 object pooling classes.

### MonoObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour

```
/// <summary>
/// Object pooler class which can hold a single type of objects.
/// </summary>
public class MonoObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Object to be pooled.
    /// </summary>
    public PooledObject PooledObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// List to store all the objects that will be pooled.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<GameObject> pooledObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Create the pooled object if the CreateOnAwake variable is set to true.
        if (PooledObject.CreateOnAwake)
        {
            Populate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the list of pooled objects with PooledObjects.
    /// </summary>
    public void Populate()
    {
        //Clear the previous items in the list.
        pooledObjects.Clear();

        //Load the items again
        for (int i = 0; i < PooledObject.Amount; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(PooledObject.Object);
            obj.SetActive(false);
            pooledObjects.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a PooledObject.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject GetPooledObject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!pooledObjects[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                //we have an available object
                return pooledObjects[i];
            }
        }
        if (PooledObject.CanGrow)
        {
            //we ran out of objects but we can create more
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(PooledObject.Object);
            pooledObjects.Add(obj);
            return obj;
        }
        //We ran out of objects and we cant create more
        return null;
    }
}
```

### PolyObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour

```
/// <summary>
/// Object pooler class which can hold many different types of objects at one place.
/// </summary>
public class PolyObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Array to store all the objects that will be pooled.
    /// </summary>
    public PooledObject[] ObjectsToPool;

    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary which holds all the created objects i.e the one you get objects from.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>> pooledObjects =
        new Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary to hold information about each separate pooled object.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, PooledObject> pooledObjectsContainer =
        new Dictionary<string, PooledObject>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Load all the required info into the dictionary.
        foreach (PooledObject objectToPool in ObjectsToPool)
        {
            pooledObjects.Add(objectToPool.Name, new List<GameObject>());
            pooledObjectsContainer.Add(objectToPool.Name, objectToPool);

            //Create any pooled object with the CreateOnAwake variable set to true.
            if (objectToPool.CreateOnAwake)
            {
                Populate(objectToPool.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates objects by a specified pooled object name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectName"> The name of the pooled object. </param>
    public void Populate(string objectName)
    {
        //Clear the previous items in the list.
        pooledObjects[objectName].Clear();

        //Load the items again
        for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjectsContainer[objectName].Amount; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(pooledObjectsContainer[objectName].Object);
            obj.SetActive(false);
            pooledObjects[objectName].Add(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a GameObject by a specified pooled object name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectName">The name of the pooled object.</param>
    public GameObject GetPooledObject(string objectName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects[objectName].Count; i++)
        {
            if (!pooledObjects[objectName][i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                //we have an available object
                return pooledObjects[objectName][i];
            }
        }
        if (pooledObjectsContainer[objectName].CanGrow)
        {
            //we ran out of objects but we can create more
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(pooledObjectsContainer[objectName].Object);
            pooledObjects[objectName].Add(obj);
            return obj;
        }
        //We ran out of objects and we cant create more
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code is relatively short and I putted a lot of comments for each method so it should be easy to understand and follow the logic, any performance and code style improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Unity, so it's hard for me to comment on design. But I do have some experience with pools, so I want to point out, that depending on pool size this linear O(n) search:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects.Count; i++)
> {
>     if (!pooledObjects[i].activeInHierarchy)
>     {
>         //we have an available object
>         return pooledObjects[i];
>     }
> }
> ```

can quickly become a serious performance bottleneck, that will negate any performance gains normally associated with pools. This problem is usually solved by actually removing "in-use" objects from the pool. And explicitly adding them back once pooled object is "released". This guaranties that any object that is present in the pool at any given time is *not* "in-use" so you can just "pop" the first one on every request (no search is needed). However, I do not know whether or not such design is applicable to Unity.

Also, both classes look like they can use a common ancestor and/or separate `ObjectPool<T>` component to represent generic re-usable pool (SRP). As it stands, instantiation logic, population logic, search logic, etc. are basically copy-pasted.